# Replace hash value based on the value in another hash

Tags: ruby, hash

Given two hashes, I'm trying to replace a value in the first hash for a key that the second hash also has. To be specific, I have these two hashes:

```
data = {
  "study"       => "Lucid Study",
  "name"        => "Lucid Plan",
  "studyWillBe" => "Combination"
}

conditions = { "study" => "((current))" }
```

I want `data` to have its `"study"` key updated since `conditions` has that key. I want `data` to end up like this:

```
data = {
  "study"       => "((current))",
  "name"        => "Lucid Plan",
  "studyWillBe" => "Combination"
}
```

I got this far:

```
data = Hash[data.map {|k, v| [conditions[k] || k, v] }]
```

but that's not quite doing the trick. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this

`data.each {|k, v| data[k] = conditions[k] if conditions[k]}`

Comment: This is perfect and does exactly what I need. Thank you very much for the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

It's called [merge](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge).

```
data = {"study"=>"Lucid Study", "name"=>"Lucid Plan", "studyWillBe"=>"Combination"}
conditions = {"study"=>"((current))"}

data.merge(conditions)
#{"study"=>"((current))", "name"=>"Lucid Plan", "studyWillBe"=>"Combination"}
```

Comment: This will give wrong result when `conditions` has a key that `data` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

The method merge can take a block where you can make some specific operation not only assign new value

```
data.merge(conditions) do |key, oldvalue, newvalue|
  newvalue
end    
=> {"study"=>"((current))", "name"=>"Lucid Plan", "studyWillBe"=>"Combination"}
```